# Use JOINS based on search results

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to show results, with data from different tables using a JOIN, based on the search results of 2 fields.

Field 1: Social Number (table 1)
Field 2: Vehicle Number (table 2)

Based on the data entered i would like to call data from Table 1 and 2, but also table 3 which is joined with table 2.

I'm familiar with the JOIN function, but not sure how to use it in combination the data entered in the 2 fields. Could anyone give me a tip to start with?

Example:

Social Number (Table 1): 1234567
Vehicle Number (Table 2): 007799

When i press: Search, i want to show the values of some fields from Table 2, show some value of fields in Table 2. But also: 1 Social Number can be linked to multiple Vehicle numbers.

I'm not sure how to start this is, i'm not asking for the whole code, i think i can figure it out myself, but i would very appreciate a tip for starting.

Table Scheme:

```
**Person**
ID
Name 
Address
SocialNumber
Licensetype

**Vehicle**
ID
VehicleNumber
Weight
Type
PersonID (Join with Person table)


**Licensetype**
ID
Licensetype (JOIN with Person table)

**VehicleType**
ID
Vehicletype (JOIN with Vehicle table)
```

Basicly, when i fill in the Social Number AND the Vehicle Number, i want to check if that person, based on the license type and vehicle type, is applicable to drive that vehicle.

Besides that, i want to show the other Vehicles that person owns.

I have tried with the following JOIN:

```
SELECT Person.PID
     , Person.name
     , Person.SocialNumber
  FROM Person
  JOIN Vehicle
    ON Vehicle.VehicleNumber
    AND Vehicle.Vehicletype
  JOIN License
    ON License.Licensetype
```

But i'm not sure how to combine this join with 2 search fields in 1 search action. Am i doing it right, when i only use 1 search field?

EDIT: Here is my DB Structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wztLM.png

I want to create 2 search fields:

1 to search on value 1: "BSNNummer" (Social number)
1 to search on value 2: "Kenteken" (License plate)

When i fill in both fields, Social number & License plate, i want to check via "Check 1, Check 2 and Check 3" to see if the Driving License (Rijbewijs) of the person (wherefore i fill in the social number) is still valid (Geldigheid) and has the right type to drive the Vehicle (Voertuig) which is, for example: a Motorcycle.

So, if you have a driver license for only a car, the result if you are applicable to drive a motor is: No.

I have no idea how to start with the 2 search fields and combine the fields. Therefor i would really appreciate a start up.

Comment: Please provide your table schema at least.

Comment: No, some SQL where you attempted it would be the very least.

Comment: Do a where once the data is joined.  phpMyAdmin has a built in function builder that can run a search on joins.

Comment: @Frederic; I have edited my post with some tables and have cleared it up a little bit. @eyeLoveFiddle, thanks, i'll that a look at that in the meanwhile!!@developerwjk;I understand, i've tried, but realised i was using some lines totally not applicable with the results i wanted.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sql code that you are working with.

Comment: As others have indicated, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, i have created my database structure and linked to an image in the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Once you join the various tables together you can use a **where** clause on any part of it. If I understand your table schema properly you'd end up with something akin to:

```
select * from Person pp join Vehicle vv
on pp.Id = Vehicle.PersonId
join LicenseType lt on lt.LicenseType = pp.LicenseType
join VehicleType vt on vt.VehicleType = vv.Type
where BSNNummer = <something> and Kenteken = <something else>
and .. < so on >
```

If you get any sort of value back you know you have a complete match since these are all inner joins.

Note - the join from *license* to *person* looks a bit sketchy (among other things). I couldn't understand the language used in your graphic so I had to go on the schema you included here.